# Outputting Powershell Script elements to a log file

Tags: powershell

I have the script below.

```
$log = "C:\DNSLog.txt"

############ GET THE LIST OF RECORDS
$zones = Get-Content "C:\dnslist.txt"

############ TRANSFER THE ZONES TO THE MASTER SERVER
Write-Host "Transferring the zones to the master server..."
foreach ($zone in $zones) {
    Write-Host $zone >> $log
    dnscmd . /zoneadd $zone /Secondary 10.x.x.x >> $log
}
```

This doesn't seem to be outputting what I need to the log file.  All I am getting is the "write-host" portion.  No feedback from the "dnscmd" command.  I would expect to see this (because the zone already exists in this case, but you get the point for success/failure):

```
domain1.com

Command failed:  DNS_ERROR_ZONE_ALREADY_EXISTS     9609    0x2589
```

If I just do:

```
    Write-Host $zone
    dnscmd . /zoneadd $zone /Secondary 10.x.x.x >> $log
```

I get the dnscmd output and no "write-host" feedback (as expected).  What am I doing wrong that won't let me get the "write-host AND the dnscmd output in the log file???

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Host` only writes to the console, and apparently its output cannot be redirected to a file.  You should use `Write-Output` instead.

Notice that `Write-Host` has options for `-Foreground` and `-Background` color, which leads to the idea that it is really intended just for writing to the console window.

Comment: Yeah that did it.  Thank you so much.  Still learning this nifty powershell tool.  Lots of cmdlets and options to master.  :)  Thank you.

Comment: Can you "accept" the answer ? We both get a few extra points that way. Thanks !

Comment: Write-Host output can be redirected if you use Start-Transcript but Start-Transcript has the issue of not being able to capture exe output.  That is fixed in V5.   Write-Host output can also be captured like this:  `powershell.exe -command "& {Write-Host 'testing write-host'}" > test.log`